# ngCordova Barcode Scanner - Keep camera open after scanning

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ngcordova

I've used the example code from the documentation to create a simple barcode scanner:

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/

After scanning each barcode the camera window is closed and I'm presented with the result.  Is there any way I can keep the camera window open and display the result in an alert or something on screen? This is so the user can scan lots of barcodes at once.

Comment: No, you have to rewrite the plugin. I'm not sure, but I think that the plugin from Scandit allows scanning in a serie https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin

Answer (score 0):

In ngCordova barcodeScanner you can't scan in a serie. The easiest way would be to look for another plugin that lets you execute it.